# Passing value to FindById method using Generic types doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a repository for all my entities like this :

```
 public abstract class GenericRepository<C, T> :
    IGenericRepository<T>
        where T : class
        where C : DbContext, new()
    {

        private C _entities = new C();
        public C Context
        {

            get { return _entities; }
            set { _entities = value; }
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {

            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>();
            return query;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {

            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
            return query;
        }

        public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Edit(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public virtual void Save()
        {
            _entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

So i create a **User repository** that inherences from the above class as you can see here :

```
public  class userRepository:GenericRepository<InModelContainer,User>
  {
    }
```

My problem is ,how can i call **FindBy()** method in my class ,My **User entity** is like this :

```
  public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            this.Ideas = new HashSet<Idea>();
            this.Companies = new HashSet<Company>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("نام")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "نام را وارد کنید")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

I need to find a **User** By **id**,so i have to use **findBy** method but i don't know how can i call this method .

Example:

```
 userRepository objRepository= new userRepository();
       public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
           return View(objRepository.FindBy());
        }
```

What should i pass to the above function ?

Best regards.

I am using MVC4 and EF6.

Comment: why dont you pass it the id?

Comment: I pass it the id ,but as you can see ,The findBy expect something else.when i pass id to it ,i got an error

Comment: objRepository.FindBy(i=>i.Id== id)

Comment: @linodh i changed it to **return View(objRepository.FindBy(i=>i.Id==id));** but i got this error :argument type iqueryable<domainclass.user> is npt assignable to domainclass.user

Comment: you are trying to assign a collection to an object thats why. use objRepository.FindBy(i=>i.Id== id).FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
   userRepository objRepository= new userRepository();
   public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
       return View(objRepository.FindBy(user => user.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());
    }
```

this will filter users based on the id and will take the first one or null if there is no match. You can choose to use .First() also if you want an exception instead.